# Git alias an export repo cmd (git archive | tar)

Tags: git

I have the command:

`git archive --format=tar --remote git@remoteid:repoid tagid | tar -xf -`

Which takes the git repo "repoid" from the remote "remoteid" and exports the repo at the tag "tagid" to the current directory. However, when I try to add this as a git alias command, it doesn't work. It doesn't give me any errors; it simply doesn't produce the expected result.

git alias command:

`[alias]
export1 = !sh -c 'git archive --format=tar --remote git@$1:$2 $3 | tar -xf -' -
export2 = !sh -c 'git archive --format=tar --remote $1 $2 | tar -xf -' -`

called as

`git export1 remoteid repoid tagid
git export2 git@remoteid:repoid tagid`

I know the structure for the alias work with other commands just not this export. For example:

`[alias]
deletetag = !sh -c 'git tag -d $1 && git push origin :refs/tags/$1' -`

called as

`git deletetag V1.01.000`

Will remove the tag from the local repo and the remote origin repo.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay so I've discovered a very interesting part to this issue. The git alias above "export1" does work as long as your current directory is not within an existing git repo. However, if your current directory is within an existing git repo it exports the files to the root of that existing repo. So the question now is: is there a way to get the executing directory for a git alias? Unfortunately $PWD returns the git repo root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot edit my post to put the solution I discovered in the question. Anyway,

The initial problem seemed to be that git aliases do not run at the current directory if it is within an existing git repo. Instead they run at the root of that repo. So the alias was working just not putting the files where I wanted them. To fix this I was able to change the alias to:

```
export = !sh -c 'git archive --format=tar --remote git@$1:$2 $3 | tar -xf - -C $PWD/$GIT_PREFIX' -
```

Which work both within an existing git repo and not within one.